# Is it possible to get an immigration visa (to stay as long as possible) to US while working remotely for a company in another country?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, polish-citizens

I've been working remotely for this Japanese company for 5 years now. I get paid more than enough to afford living in the US. I've always wanted to move there. Is it possible to get a visa like that without finding a job in the US first? I'm a Polish (EU) citizen.

Comment: Questions about long term immigration, visas and work permits belong on [expatriates.se].

Answer (score 4):

You need either:

1. Family ties
2. A qualifying job offer,
3. Sufficient skills to qualify for a *National Interest Waiver*
4. Invest a million USD in a qualified commercial enterprise (or USD 500 000 in a high-unemployment area or rural area)
5. Participate and be selected the Diversity lottery.

Then you follow the process for getting an immigrant visa, and you must enter the US within 6 months of the visa being issued.

THen, you must maintain the US as your main home, and cannot be out of the country for more than a year at once without advance permission.

Comment: A job offer by itself is not sufficient.  It must be a job offer for position that qualifies for an employment-based visa from a company that will file a sponsorship application.  Many of those employment visas are nonimmigrant visas but formally recognized as "dual intent," meaning that the employer can subsequently sponsor the employee for permanent resident status.

Comment: @phoog Edited..